# Geometric nature and Cartesian equation of a vector space

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

> Determine the geometric nature and the Cartesian equation of the sub-vector space of $\Bbb R^2$ spanned by the first two column vector of A.

A is a matrix defined by:

$$A =\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1& 1&3\\
1&2&3 \\
1&-1&-1\\
\end{array} \right) $$

I don't understand the question, what does the ***geometric nature*** and ***cartesian equation*** mean?

Comment: If the question is from a book, there will be a definition / example somewhere. If it is from a homework sheet, you might want to ask your instructor.

Comment: @Listing I couldn't find any definition anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two columns span a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The geometric nature of that subspace is a *plane* (it is two dimensional), and the Cartesian equation of this plane is $-3x + 2y + z = 0$.

The interested Reader can verify this last claim by substituting the entries of each of the first two columns in this (linear homogeneous) equation, so that solutions of this equation contain the first two columns and (by the principle of superposition) all linear combinations of them, i.e. their span.  Since the plane and the solutions of the linear equation are both two dimensional, they are equal.